# Embed Photo Gallery in Webpage

Tags: jquery, html, photo-gallery

I have a client that is looking to embed a photo gallery from a 3rd party image hosting site (Flickr, Instagram, etc.) into a webpage. I used to be able to do this quite simply with Flickr, but it is no longer supported.

Almost everyone supports doing slideshows, but I'm not looking for a slideshow, I want each image displayed on the client's website and updated as the client uploads new photos to the image hosting service. This is not a Wordpress site.

I looked at Embedly, but it was not clear that it will work, and I have been unable to find any examples in action to confirm/refute this.

Does anyone know of  way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't really understand second paragraph.

Comment: If you tell me what you don't understand I will attempt to clear it up for you. I don't really know how to make it any clearer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

- Please explain your question,
  Sharing a simple example to getting images(plus any details regarding post) and updating old and new posts (with CRON Job).
  Open any account on Instagram check view source.
  You can see under script tag (`window._sharedData =`) there is a `JSON (`with all details of first 12 posts).

You can use that download images and other details and can be use as per your requirements.

Example: http://tecorb.com/admin/instagram_scraper/bootstrap/

```
it's a screen scraping, will prefer not to be used.
```

- **Please explain your question, So i can give you more relevant answer.**

Comment: My question is explained, I am not being difficult, I am simply not following you. A client wants to embed his Flickr gallery into his webpage. Do you know a way to do that since Flickr no longer supports the method they used to use. I don't have an example, because I can't do it. 

As far as the rest of what you wrote about CRON job, etc....that makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Hi, I am taking about Instagram, (how to show images from instagram, without API ).
That means scraping (downloading images from intagram account page)
through there JSON (check view state).